# Moving caption of the algorithm upwards

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, algorithms

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

 AAAA

 BBBB

 \begin{algorithm}
 \vspace*{-1cm}
 \caption{My Caption\ldots}
 My Code
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which does not move the "My Code" part with the caption "My Caption" upwards - but it works for figure environement - any suggestions how this can be done for the algorithms?

NOTE: I know a way of specifying the \vpsace* above the \begin{algorithm} but that won't work if you have a text arround it - it will mess up the text, and not move the algorithm.

Comment: To squeeze in one page :) No, your suggestion will not work if you have a lot of text before and after your algorithm - the vpsace*{-5mm} will affect the text only :/

Comment: Works for the example I wrote here, but does not work in reality - it just moves upwards the text :/ Isn't there a similar way as with figures/images?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about algorithms that have to stay in place.

So you have two possibilities.

1. Use `H` as a floating specifier. In this way all the spacing around the `algorithm` environment is removed.

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}

   \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

   \begin{document}

    AAAA

    BBBB

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{My Caption\ldots}
    My Code
    \end{algorithm}

    CCCC

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use `h` as a floating specifier and redefine locally the length `\intextsep` (which represents the distance between floats and text when using `h`).

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}

   \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

   \begin{document}

    AAAA

    BBBB

   {\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{My Caption\ldots}
    My Code
    \end{algorithm}
   }

    CCCC

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]